# Why is there extra white space at bottom of page when using xtab and multicol?

Tags: tables, white-space, xtab

Below is my MWE. As seen when complied and on the PDF there is seemingly a large amount of white space on the bottom but not on the top. I have searched around to try and find an answer but as of yet, I have been unsuccessful. Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xtab, booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=5mm, bottom=5mm, right=10mm, left=10mm}

\twocolumn

\subsection{P/E ratios by industry}

\begin{xtabular}{| p{5.5cm} | p{2cm}|}
\hline
 Industry Name & PE ratio \\ \hline
Advertising Agencies & 13.8317\\\hline
Aerospace \& Defense & 21.581 \\ \hline
Agricultural Inputs & 6.7312 \\ \hline
Airlines & 7.548 \\ \hline
Airports \& Air Services & 15.5786 \\ \hline
Aluminum & 7.0279 \\ \hline
Apparel Manufacturing & 12.2794\\ \hline
Apparel Retail & 23.4612 \\ \hline
Asset Management& 13.0169\\ \hline
Auto \& Truck Dealerships& 10.6548\\ \hline
Auto Manufacturers& 11.9223\\ \hline
Auto Parts& 15.7441 \\ \hline
Banks - Diversified& 6.0061\\ \hline
Banks - Regional& 7.2524\\ \hline
Beverages - Brewers& 15.2334 \\ \hline
Beverages - Non-Alcoholic & 33.6127\\ \hline
Beverages - Wineries \& Distilleries & 68.1724\\ \hline
Biotechnology & 19.2754\\ \hline
Broadcasting & 5.0258\\ \hline
Building Materials & 15.8983\\ \hline
Building Products \& Equipment & 16.3582\\ \hline
Business Equipment \& Supplies & 12.1799\\ \hline
Capital Markets & 12.34\\ \hline
Chemicals & 9.8513\\ \hline
Coking Coal & 2.5208\\ \hline
Communication Equipment & 14.7872\\ \hline
Computer Hardware & 13.9351\\ \hline
Confectioners & 35.5205\\ \hline
Conglomerates & 9.0959\\ \hline
Consulting Services & 39.5976\\ \hline
Consumer Electronics & 18.2252\\ \hline
Copper & 18.0158\\ \hline
Credit Services & 19.0924\\ \hline
Department Stores & 14.7027\\ \hline
Diagnostics \& Research & 28.5204\\ \hline
Discount Stores & 30.1424\\ \hline
Drug Manufacturers - General & 19.1644\\ \hline
Drug Manufacturers - Specialty \& Generic & 16.82\\ \hline
Education \& Training Services & 1.4482\\ \hline
Electrical Equipment \& Parts & 17.1368\\ \hline
Electronic Components & 15.5031\\ \hline
Electronic Gaming \& Multimedia & 21.6019\\ \hline
Electronics \& Computer Distribution & 8.6529\\ \hline
Engineering \& Construction & 14.4651\\ \hline
Entertainment & 30.3976\\ \hline
Farm \& Heavy Construction Machinery & 12.8073\\ \hline
Farm Products & 10.8738\\ \hline
Financial Conglomerates & 10.778\\ \hline
Financial Data \& Stock Exchanges & 35.0621\\ \hline
Food Distribution & 20.5961\\ \hline
Footwear \& Accessories & 29.9109\\ \hline
Furnishings, Fixtures \& Appliances & 13.0217\\ \hline
Gambling & 9.5984\\ \hline
Gold & 21.3192\\ \hline
Grocery Stores & 15.354\\ \hline
Health Information Services & 49.0714\\ \hline
Healthcare Plans & 21.8047\\ \hline
Home Improvement Retail & 17.1846\\ \hline
Household \& Personal Products & 29.8998\\ \hline
Industrial Distribution & 16.6399\\ \hline
Information Technology Services & 24.0642\\ \hline
Infrastructure Operations & 8.2783\\ \hline
Insurance - Diversified & 8.9628\\ \hline
Insurance - Life & 9.0771\\ \hline
Insurance - Property \& Casualty & 15.7013\\ \hline
Insurance - Reinsurance & 10.962\\ \hline
Insurance - Specialty & 8.524\\ \hline
Insurance Brokers & 29.7146\\ \hline
Integrated Freight \& Logistics & 13.2508\\ \hline
Internet Content \& Information & 24.1213\\ \hline
Internet Retail & 54.7509\\ \hline
Leisure & 22.2916\\ \hline
Lodging & 19.3584\\ \hline
Lumber \& Wood Production & 10.7744\\ \hline
Luxury Goods & 8.8629\\ \hline
Marine Shipping & 2.1237\\ \hline
Medical Care Facilities & 14.5794\\ \hline
Medical Devices & 38.0792\\ \hline
Medical Distribution & 14.1076\\ \hline
Medical Instruments \& Supplies & 43.1705\\ \hline
Metal Fabrication & 11.0632\\ \hline
Mortgage Finance & 0.8573\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Drilling & 1.4489\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas E\&P & 4.4654\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Equipment \& Services & 12.7641\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Integrated & 4.8799\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Midstream & 9.9221\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Refining \& Marketing & 4.0411\\ \hline
Other Industrial Metals \& Mining & 7.1972\\ \hline
Other Precious Metals \& Mining & 18.4958\\ \hline
Packaged Foods & 17.9473\\ \hline
Packaging \& Containers & 13.9331\\ \hline
Paper \& Paper Products & 6.3122\\ \hline
Personal Services & 32.6419\\ \hline
Pharmaceutical Retailers & 20.2719\\ \hline
Pollution \& Treatment Controls & 29.908\\ \hline
Publishing & 17.4996\\ \hline
Railroads & 16.7928\\ \hline
Real Estate - Development & 7.405\\ \hline
Real Estate - Diversified & 15.2917\\ \hline
Real Estate Services & 14.2196\\ \hline
Recreational Vehicles & 8.2577\\ \hline
REIT - Diversified & 13.9647\\ \hline
REIT - Healthcare Facilities & 45.5218\\ \hline
REIT - Hotel \& Motel & 15.3049\\ \hline
REIT - Industrial & 22.3663\\ \hline
REIT - Mortgage & 9.2096\\ \hline
REIT - Office & 17.2735\\ \hline
REIT - Residential & 26.0129\\ \hline
REIT - Retail & 21.8934\\ \hline
REIT - Specialty & 48.1218\\ \hline
Rental \& Leasing Services & 8.8913\\ \hline
Residential Construction & 6.0154\\ \hline
Resorts \& Casinos & 11.838\\ \hline
Restaurants & 28.2678\\ \hline
Scientific \& Technical Instruments & 30.1633\\ \hline
Security \& Protection Services & 17.4653\\ \hline
Semiconductor Equipment \& Materials & 19.9236\\ \hline
Semiconductors & 21.4593\\ \hline
Shell Companies & 35.7939\\ \hline
Silver & 24.2277\\ \hline
Software - Application & 56.6311\\ \hline
Software - Infrastructure & 30.9855\\ \hline
Solar & 34.7856\\ \hline
Specialty Business Services & 34.9896\\ \hline
Specialty Chemicals & 14.2669\\ \hline
Specialty Industrial Machinery & 21.5089\\ \hline
Specialty Retail & 15.2014\\ \hline
Staffing \& Employment Services & 21.1407\\ \hline
Steel & 5.8997\\ \hline
Telecom Services & 14.5328\\ \hline
Textile Manufacturing & 14.2738\\ \hline
Thermal Coal & 4.2015\\ \hline
Tobacco & 13.4528\\ \hline
Tools \& Accessories & 18.7788\\ \hline
Travel Services & 24.6018\\ \hline
Trucking & 15.3906\\ \hline
Uranium & 18.9373\\ \hline
Utilities - Diversified & 19.6534\\ \hline
Utilities - Independent Power Producers & 4.9407\\ \hline
Utilities - Regulated Electric & 21.868\\ \hline
Utilities - Regulated Gas & 12.0797\\ \hline
Utilities - Regulated Water & 22.4195\\ \hline
Utilities - Renewable & 4.9562\\ \hline
Waste Management & 27.8048\\ \hline
\end{xtabular}

\restoregeometry 

\end{document}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This seems the expected behaviour. The default vertical behaviour of multicol is that columns are flush to the top, and if there’s not enough content to fill the whole page, the column-break is placed to keep column bottoms even, unless you issue `\raggedcolumns` in which case column breaks are placed as late in content as possible. As you have `xcol`, your table gets flowed/broken just like normal text content. I guess you want the whole thing vertically centred on the page; in that case perhaps make it a floating figure/table?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine `multicol` is indeed loaded in the example and also appears in the title of the question. However, it is not used at all in the example. So not `multicol` but `xtab` is responsible for the column breaks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: Currently you are loading `multicol` but you are not using it. So the question is independent from this package and so is my answer. (BTW: `booktabs` is also loaded but not used.)

`xtab` is a `supertabular` extension. And too early page breaks (in your case column breaks) are IMHO not really seldom with `supertabular` or `xtab`. However, there are commands in `xtab` to manipulate the page break somehow. Maybe the following is more, what you'd expect:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xtab, booktabs}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=5mm, bottom=5mm, right=10mm, left=10mm}

\twocolumn[\subsection{P/E ratios by industry}]

\tabletail{\hline}
\xentrystretch{0.05}
\begin{xtabular}{| p{5.5cm} | p{2cm}|}
\hline
 Industry Name & PE ratio \\ \hline
Advertising Agencies & 13.8317\\\hline
Aerospace \& Defense & 21.581 \\ \hline
Agricultural Inputs & 6.7312 \\ \hline
Airlines & 7.548 \\ \hline
Airports \& Air Services & 15.5786 \\ \hline
Aluminum & 7.0279 \\ \hline
Apparel Manufacturing & 12.2794\\ \hline
Apparel Retail & 23.4612 \\ \hline
Asset Management& 13.0169\\ \hline
Auto \& Truck Dealerships& 10.6548\\ \hline
Auto Manufacturers& 11.9223\\ \hline
Auto Parts& 15.7441 \\ \hline
Banks - Diversified& 6.0061\\ \hline
Banks - Regional& 7.2524\\ \hline
Beverages - Brewers& 15.2334 \\ \hline
Beverages - Non-Alcoholic & 33.6127\\ \hline
Beverages - Wineries \& Distilleries & 68.1724\\ \hline
Biotechnology & 19.2754\\ \hline
Broadcasting & 5.0258\\ \hline
Building Materials & 15.8983\\ \hline
Building Products \& Equipment & 16.3582\\ \hline
Business Equipment \& Supplies & 12.1799\\ \hline
Capital Markets & 12.34\\ \hline
Chemicals & 9.8513\\ \hline
Coking Coal & 2.5208\\ \hline
Communication Equipment & 14.7872\\ \hline
Computer Hardware & 13.9351\\ \hline
Confectioners & 35.5205\\ \hline
Conglomerates & 9.0959\\ \hline
Consulting Services & 39.5976\\ \hline
Consumer Electronics & 18.2252\\ \hline
Copper & 18.0158\\ \hline
Credit Services & 19.0924\\ \hline
Department Stores & 14.7027\\ \hline
Diagnostics \& Research & 28.5204\\ \hline
Discount Stores & 30.1424\\ \hline
Drug Manufacturers - General & 19.1644\\ \hline
Drug Manufacturers - Specialty \& Generic & 16.82\\ \hline
Education \& Training Services & 1.4482\\ \hline
Electrical Equipment \& Parts & 17.1368\\ \hline
Electronic Components & 15.5031\\ \hline
Electronic Gaming \& Multimedia & 21.6019\\ \hline
Electronics \& Computer Distribution & 8.6529\\ \hline
Engineering \& Construction & 14.4651\\ \hline
Entertainment & 30.3976\\ \hline
Farm \& Heavy Construction Machinery & 12.8073\\ \hline
Farm Products & 10.8738\\ \hline
Financial Conglomerates & 10.778\\ \hline
Financial Data \& Stock Exchanges & 35.0621\\ \hline
Food Distribution & 20.5961\\ \hline
Footwear \& Accessories & 29.9109\\ \hline
Furnishings, Fixtures \& Appliances & 13.0217\\ \hline
Gambling & 9.5984\\ \hline
Gold & 21.3192\\ \hline
Grocery Stores & 15.354\\ \hline
Health Information Services & 49.0714\\ \hline
Healthcare Plans & 21.8047\\ \hline
Home Improvement Retail & 17.1846\\ \hline
Household \& Personal Products & 29.8998\\ \hline
Industrial Distribution & 16.6399\\ \hline
Information Technology Services & 24.0642\\ \hline
Infrastructure Operations & 8.2783\\ \hline
Insurance - Diversified & 8.9628\\ \hline
Insurance - Life & 9.0771\\ \hline
Insurance - Property \& Casualty & 15.7013\\ \hline
Insurance - Reinsurance & 10.962\\ \hline
Insurance - Specialty & 8.524\\ \hline
Insurance Brokers & 29.7146\\ \hline
Integrated Freight \& Logistics & 13.2508\\ \hline
Internet Content \& Information & 24.1213\\ \hline
Internet Retail & 54.7509\\ \hline
Leisure & 22.2916\\ \hline
Lodging & 19.3584\\ \hline
Lumber \& Wood Production & 10.7744\\ \hline
Luxury Goods & 8.8629\\ \hline
Marine Shipping & 2.1237\\ \hline
Medical Care Facilities & 14.5794\\ \hline
Medical Devices & 38.0792\\ \hline
Medical Distribution & 14.1076\\ \hline
Medical Instruments \& Supplies & 43.1705\\ \hline
Metal Fabrication & 11.0632\\ \hline
Mortgage Finance & 0.8573\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Drilling & 1.4489\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas E\&P & 4.4654\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Equipment \& Services & 12.7641\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Integrated & 4.8799\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Midstream & 9.9221\\ \hline
Oil \& Gas Refining \& Marketing & 4.0411\\ \hline
Other Industrial Metals \& Mining & 7.1972\\ \hline
Other Precious Metals \& Mining & 18.4958\\ \hline
Packaged Foods & 17.9473\\ \hline
Packaging \& Containers & 13.9331\\ \hline
Paper \& Paper Products & 6.3122\\ \hline
Personal Services & 32.6419\\ \hline
Pharmaceutical Retailers & 20.2719\\ \hline
Pollution \& Treatment Controls & 29.908\\ \hline
Publishing & 17.4996\\ \hline
Railroads & 16.7928\\ \hline
Real Estate - Development & 7.405\\ \hline
Real Estate - Diversified & 15.2917\\ \hline
Real Estate Services & 14.2196\\ \hline
Recreational Vehicles & 8.2577\\ \hline
REIT - Diversified & 13.9647\\ \hline
REIT - Healthcare Facilities & 45.5218\\ \hline
REIT - Hotel \& Motel & 15.3049\\ \hline
REIT - Industrial & 22.3663\\ \hline
REIT - Mortgage & 9.2096\\ \hline
REIT - Office & 17.2735\\ \hline
REIT - Residential & 26.0129\\ \hline
REIT - Retail & 21.8934\\ \hline
REIT - Specialty & 48.1218\\ \hline
Rental \& Leasing Services & 8.8913\\ \hline
Residential Construction & 6.0154\\ \hline
Resorts \& Casinos & 11.838\\ \hline
Restaurants & 28.2678\\ \hline
Scientific \& Technical Instruments & 30.1633\\ \hline
Security \& Protection Services & 17.4653\\ \hline
Semiconductor Equipment \& Materials & 19.9236\\ \hline
Semiconductors & 21.4593\\ \hline
Shell Companies & 35.7939\\ \hline
Silver & 24.2277\\ \hline
Software - Application & 56.6311\\ \hline
Software - Infrastructure & 30.9855\\ \hline
Solar & 34.7856\\ \hline
Specialty Business Services & 34.9896\\ \hline
Specialty Chemicals & 14.2669\\ \hline
Specialty Industrial Machinery & 21.5089\\ \hline
Specialty Retail & 15.2014\\ \hline
Staffing \& Employment Services & 21.1407\\ \hline
Steel & 5.8997\\ \hline
Telecom Services & 14.5328\\ \hline
Textile Manufacturing & 14.2738\\ \hline
Thermal Coal & 4.2015\\ \hline
Tobacco & 13.4528\\ \hline
Tools \& Accessories & 18.7788\\ \hline
Travel Services & 24.6018\\ \hline
Trucking & 15.3906\\ \hline
Uranium & 18.9373\\ \hline
Utilities - Diversified & 19.6534\\ \hline
Utilities - Independent Power Producers & 4.9407\\ \hline
Utilities - Regulated Electric & 21.868\\ \hline
Utilities - Regulated Gas & 12.0797\\ \hline
Utilities - Regulated Water & 22.4195\\ \hline
Utilities - Renewable & 4.9562\\ \hline
Waste Management & 27.8048\\ \hline
\end{xtabular}

\restoregeometry 

\end{document}
```

[image]

First of all, I've used the optional argument of `\twocolumn` to place the `\subsection` above the whole table, not only above the first column. Then I've used `\tabletail` to always add a final `\hline`, when a page/column break happens. This avoids bottom open rows. IMHO users would expect, that a bottom opened table row is continued at the next page resp. page column. So this change improves the table. Last but not least, I've changed `\xentrystretch` to modify the page/column break. The suitable value has been found by try-and-error (one try and no error, because the default it 0.1 and I've started with half of it ;-) ).

But maybe *using* `booktabs` and additionally package `siunitx` and additionally also repeating the table head would be the better suggestion:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xtab, booktabs}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[textheight=10cm]{geometry}   %% just for this example.

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{top=5mm, bottom=5mm, right=10mm, left=10mm}

\twocolumn[\subsection{P/E ratios by industry}]

\tabletail{\bottomrule}
\tablehead{%
  \toprule
  Industry Name & {PE ratio} \\ 
  \midrule
}
\sisetup{table-format=3.4}
\begin{xtabular}{p{\columnwidth-4\tabcolsep-4em}p{4em}}
Advertising Agencies & \tablenum{13.8317}\\
Aerospace \& Defense & \tablenum{21.581 }\\ 
Agricultural Inputs & \tablenum{6.7312 }\\ 
Airlines & \tablenum{7.548 }\\ 
Airports \& Air Services & \tablenum{15.5786 }\\ 
Aluminum & \tablenum{7.0279 }\\ 
Apparel Manufacturing & \tablenum{12.2794}\\ 
Apparel Retail & \tablenum{23.4612 }\\ 
Asset Management& \tablenum{13.0169}\\ 
Auto \& Truck Dealerships& \tablenum{10.6548}\\ 
Auto Manufacturers& \tablenum{11.9223}\\ 
Auto Parts& \tablenum{15.7441 }\\ 
Banks - Diversified& \tablenum{6.0061}\\ 
Banks - Regional& \tablenum{7.2524}\\ 
Beverages - Brewers& \tablenum{15.2334 }\\ 
Beverages - Non-Alcoholic & \tablenum{33.6127}\\ 
Beverages - Wineries \& Distilleries & \tablenum{68.1724}\\ 
Biotechnology & \tablenum{19.2754}\\ 
Broadcasting & \tablenum{5.0258}\\ 
Building Materials & \tablenum{15.8983}\\ 
Building Products \& Equipment & \tablenum{16.3582}\\ 
Business Equipment \& Supplies & \tablenum{12.1799}\\ 
Capital Markets & \tablenum{12.34}\\ 
Chemicals & \tablenum{9.8513}\\ 
Coking Coal & \tablenum{2.5208}\\ 
Communication Equipment & \tablenum{14.7872}\\ 
Computer Hardware & \tablenum{13.9351}\\ 
Confectioners & \tablenum{35.5205}\\ 
Conglomerates & \tablenum{9.0959}\\ 
Consulting Services & \tablenum{39.5976}\\ 
Consumer Electronics & \tablenum{18.2252}\\ 
Copper & \tablenum{18.0158}\\ 
Credit Services & \tablenum{19.0924}\\ 
Department Stores & \tablenum{14.7027}\\ 
Diagnostics \& Research & \tablenum{28.5204}\\ 
Discount Stores & \tablenum{30.1424}\\ 
Drug Manufacturers - General & \tablenum{19.1644}\\ 
Drug Manufacturers - Specialty \& Generic & \tablenum{16.82}\\ 
Education \& Training Services & \tablenum{1.4482}\\ 
Electrical Equipment \& Parts & \tablenum{17.1368}\\ 
Electronic Components & \tablenum{15.5031}\\ 
Electronic Gaming \& Multimedia & \tablenum{21.6019}\\ 
Electronics \& Computer Distribution & \tablenum{8.6529}\\ 
Engineering \& Construction & \tablenum{14.4651}\\ 
Entertainment & \tablenum{30.3976}\\ 
Farm \& Heavy Construction Machinery & \tablenum{12.8073}\\ 
Farm Products & \tablenum{10.8738}\\ 
Financial Conglomerates & \tablenum{10.778}\\ 
Financial Data \& Stock Exchanges & \tablenum{35.0621}\\ 
Food Distribution & \tablenum{20.5961}\\ 
Footwear \& Accessories & \tablenum{29.9109}\\ 
Furnishings, Fixtures \& Appliances & \tablenum{13.0217}\\ 
Gambling & \tablenum{9.5984}\\ 
Gold & \tablenum{21.3192}\\ 
Grocery Stores & \tablenum{15.354}\\ 
Health Information Services & \tablenum{49.0714}\\ 
Healthcare Plans & \tablenum{21.8047}\\ 
Home Improvement Retail & \tablenum{17.1846}\\ 
Household \& Personal Products & \tablenum{29.8998}\\ 
Industrial Distribution & \tablenum{16.6399}\\ 
Information Technology Services & \tablenum{24.0642}\\ 
Infrastructure Operations & \tablenum{8.2783}\\ 
Insurance - Diversified & \tablenum{8.9628}\\ 
Insurance - Life & \tablenum{9.0771}\\ 
Insurance - Property \& Casualty & \tablenum{15.7013}\\ 
Insurance - Reinsurance & \tablenum{10.962}\\ 
Insurance - Specialty & \tablenum{8.524}\\ 
Insurance Brokers & \tablenum{29.7146}\\ 
Integrated Freight \& Logistics & \tablenum{13.2508}\\ 
Internet Content \& Information & \tablenum{24.1213}\\ 
Internet Retail & \tablenum{54.7509}\\ 
Leisure & \tablenum{22.2916}\\ 
Lodging & \tablenum{19.3584}\\ 
Lumber \& Wood Production & \tablenum{10.7744}\\ 
Luxury Goods & \tablenum{8.8629}\\ 
Marine Shipping & \tablenum{2.1237}\\ 
Medical Care Facilities & \tablenum{14.5794}\\ 
Medical Devices & \tablenum{38.0792}\\ 
Medical Distribution & \tablenum{14.1076}\\ 
Medical Instruments \& Supplies & \tablenum{43.1705}\\ 
Metal Fabrication & \tablenum{11.0632}\\ 
Mortgage Finance & \tablenum{0.8573}\\ 
Oil \& Gas Drilling & \tablenum{1.4489}\\ 
Oil \& Gas E\&P & \tablenum{4.4654}\\ 
Oil \& Gas Equipment \& Services & \tablenum{12.7641}\\ 
Oil \& Gas Integrated & \tablenum{4.8799}\\ 
Oil \& Gas Midstream & \tablenum{9.9221}\\ 
Oil \& Gas Refining \& Marketing & \tablenum{4.0411}\\ 
Other Industrial Metals \& Mining & \tablenum{7.1972}\\ 
Other Precious Metals \& Mining & \tablenum{18.4958}\\ 
Packaged Foods & \tablenum{17.9473}\\ 
Packaging \& Containers & \tablenum{13.9331}\\ 
Paper \& Paper Products & \tablenum{6.3122}\\ 
Personal Services & \tablenum{32.6419}\\ 
Pharmaceutical Retailers & \tablenum{20.2719}\\ 
Pollution \& Treatment Controls & \tablenum{29.908}\\ 
Publishing & \tablenum{17.4996}\\ 
Railroads & \tablenum{16.7928}\\ 
Real Estate - Development & \tablenum{7.405}\\ 
Real Estate - Diversified & \tablenum{15.2917}\\ 
Real Estate Services & \tablenum{14.2196}\\ 
Recreational Vehicles & \tablenum{8.2577}\\ 
REIT - Diversified & \tablenum{13.9647}\\ 
REIT - Healthcare Facilities & \tablenum{45.5218}\\ 
REIT - Hotel \& Motel & \tablenum{15.3049}\\ 
REIT - Industrial & \tablenum{22.3663}\\ 
REIT - Mortgage & \tablenum{9.2096}\\ 
REIT - Office & \tablenum{17.2735}\\ 
REIT - Residential & \tablenum{26.0129}\\ 
REIT - Retail & \tablenum{21.8934}\\ 
REIT - Specialty & \tablenum{48.1218}\\ 
Rental \& Leasing Services & \tablenum{8.8913}\\ 
Residential Construction & \tablenum{6.0154}\\ 
Resorts \& Casinos & \tablenum{11.838}\\ 
Restaurants & \tablenum{28.2678}\\ 
Scientific \& Technical Instruments & \tablenum{30.1633}\\ 
Security \& Protection Services & \tablenum{17.4653}\\ 
Semiconductor Equipment \& Materials & \tablenum{19.9236}\\ 
Semiconductors & \tablenum{21.4593}\\ 
Shell Companies & \tablenum{35.7939}\\ 
Silver & \tablenum{24.2277}\\ 
Software - Application & \tablenum{56.6311}\\ 
Software - Infrastructure & \tablenum{30.9855}\\ 
Solar & \tablenum{34.7856}\\ 
Specialty Business Services & \tablenum{34.9896}\\ 
Specialty Chemicals & \tablenum{14.2669}\\ 
Specialty Industrial Machinery & \tablenum{21.5089}\\ 
Specialty Retail & \tablenum{15.2014}\\ 
Staffing \& Employment Services & \tablenum{21.1407}\\ 
Steel & \tablenum{5.8997}\\ 
Telecom Services & \tablenum{14.5328}\\ 
Textile Manufacturing & \tablenum{14.2738}\\ 
Thermal Coal & \tablenum{4.2015}\\ 
Tobacco & \tablenum{13.4528}\\ 
Tools \& Accessories & \tablenum{18.7788}\\ 
Travel Services & \tablenum{24.6018}\\ 
Trucking & \tablenum{15.3906}\\ 
Uranium & \tablenum{18.9373}\\ 
Utilities - Diversified & \tablenum{19.6534}\\ 
Utilities - Independent Power Producers & \tablenum{4.9407}\\ 
Utilities - Regulated Electric & \tablenum{21.868}\\ 
Utilities - Regulated Gas & \tablenum{12.0797}\\ 
Utilities - Regulated Water & \tablenum{22.4195}\\ 
Utilities - Renewable & \tablenum{4.9562}\\ 
Waste Management & \tablenum{27.8048}\\
\bottomrule
\end{xtabular}

\restoregeometry 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think your second answer is exactly what I was looking for!